# RobotFramework + Selenium2library - Click on link for page that uses angularjs

Tags: angularjs, selenium, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework and Selenium2Library for automating our application which uses angularjs.

I want to know if there is a way to click on an element based on ng-click="functionName()" that is if I can somehow use the functionName to click a link or button.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Xpath or CssSelector to select the element

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[ng-click=\"functionName()\"]"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-click=\"functionName()\"]"));
```

Comment: You've shown selenium commands, but you can't directly run selenium commands in a robot framework test.